# Open Office Basic cell.length

Tags: openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I have to check cells and when it is empty show MsgBox or something. So I`m looking for IsNull function or cell.length. Has BASIC some kind of this functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenOffice I would use YourCell.String == ""

Answer (score 1):

According to http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Cells_and_Ranges, you can check `Cell.Type` to see if it is equal to `com.sun.star.table.CellContentType.EMPTY`.